# How to get the default margin of printers using win32 in python

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm making a software for printing results etc using python win32. As all the printers use a default margin an it varies from printer to printer, I need the top and left margin of the printer so that I can manage my printing according to that.

I've searched and found the following:

```
PHYSICALOFFSETX = 112
PHYSICALOFFSETY = 113

printer_margins = dc.GetDeviceCaps (PHYSICALOFFSETX/PHYSICALOFFSETY), dc.GetDeviceCaps (PHYSICALOFFSETY)
```

which gives (0, 0) but when I print the page, there is a margin in my Cannon printer which is set by defualt. What actually the above code means and why this constants are used?

I need a code snippet where I can have the default margin in inch and/or twips.